# Name of compound distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I have thought of a probabilistic model as follow:

$Y$ is Poisson($\lambda$)
$X|Y$ is Binomial(Y, 0.5)

Could you please tell me what is the name of this distribution of $X$ ? (i know it is a compound distribution but don't know the name). Moreover, does $X$ has a closed-formed distribution function ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It is easier to understand this as a model of a process.  Suppose you have red and blue balls (each equally likely) turning up in a Poisson process at rate $\lambda$.  $Y$ is the number of balls which turn up in a particular unit of time, so Poisson distributed with mean $\lambda$.  $X$ is the number of red balls that turn up in that time, so unconditionally from a Poisson process with rate $\lambda/2$, and conditional on $Y$ a binomial distribution with $p=\frac12$

Comment: @Henry: thanks for your response, if i change  the distribution of $Y$ to Negative Binomial, could you please tell me what it will become because as far as i know, there is no such thing as Negative Binomial process. I'am trying to learn to compound 2 arbitrary probability distribution. Could you please suggest Any books or article about this subject ? Thank you

Comment: I have not thought about it before, but I think you could do the same for a suitably defined negative binomial.  Suppose you have a stream of iid balls: green balls with probability $g$, red with probability $\frac{1-g}2$ and blue also with probability $\frac{1-g}2$, then $Y$ could be the number of red and blue balls appearing before $n$ green balls appear, and $X$ the number of red balls appearing before $n$ green balls appear.  Then $Y\sim NB(n,g)$ and given $Y=y$ you have $X \sim Bin(y,1/2)$, while marginally $X\sim NB(n, 2g/(1+g))$ (unchecked)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get the joint pmf

$$P(X,Y)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\cdot \lambda^y}{y!}\binom{y}{x}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^y$$

Then sum w.r.t. y and after some manipulation you find that

$$P(X=x)=\frac{e^{-\lambda/2}\cdot(\lambda/2)^x}{x!}$$

That is $X\sim Po(\lambda/2)$

---

$$P(Y=y)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\cdot \lambda^y}{y!}$$

the conditional distribution is

$$P(X|Y=y)=\binom{y}{x}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^y$$

the joint pmf is

$$P_{XY}(x,y)=P_Y(y)\cdot P_{X|Y}(x|y)$$

Comment: Thanks for your help! Could you please tell me why you calculate the joint pmf $P(x,y)$ like that ? I don't get the idea

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge: is it clear enough now? can you complete the proof with my hint?